# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './app/index.vue' vue.js component import ES6

Tags: javascript, vue.js, babeljs, webpack-2

i am still practicing to use webpack2 with vue js and babel but bumped to this error. i don't know what exactly is missing.

```
ERROR in ./src/main.js 
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './app/index.vue' in 'E:\xampp\htdocs\webpack-practice\src'
@ ./src/main.js 3:0-43
```

it seems the error is coming from the line i try to import vue component here

```
//file src\main.js
import Vue from 'vue'

import AppComponent from './app/index.vue'

const vm = new Vue({
el: '#app',
components: {
    app: AppComponent,
},
render: h => h('app'),
})
```

this is my config file

```
//file webpack.config.js
var webpack = require('webpack');
module.exports = {
entry: './src/main',
output: {
    path: './build',
    filename: 'main.js',
},
module: {
    rules: [
    {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        use: { 
            loader: 'vue'               
        }
    },
    {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader'
    }
    ]
},
plugins: [
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
        vue: {
            loader: {
                js: 'babel-loader'
            }
        }
    })
]
}
```

i'm pretty sure the import path is valid, here is my folder structure. and already put ./ prefix before the folder name.

```
 root
 |----index.html
 |----webpack.config.js
 |----app
 |     |----index.vue
 |     |----some file
 |
 |----build
 |     |----main.js
 |
 |----node_modules
 |
 |----src
       |----main.js
```

what am i missing here? please help,
i'm using windows 10 if it's matter.

Comment: In such case you can answer your own question to make sure that people with similar problems can use the question and answer to resolve them

Comment: Please rollback the edit to your question and [instead post the solution as an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: done. i hope i did it properly

Answer (score 19):

i have solved my problem, since it seems i can't delete the answer. i'll edit how i solve the problem.

change this part

```
import AppComponent from './app/index.vue'
```

to

```
import AppComponent from '../app/index.vue'
```

i feel ashame to miss this kind of error.

and change the vue loader after the next error is appear

```
loader: 'vue'
```

changed to

```
loader: 'vue-loader'
```

then install others needed dependencies suggested by the terminal.

Answer (score 3):

your code :

```
  import AppComponent from './app/index.vue'
```

convert to :

```
import AppComponent from '../app/ index.vue'
```

OR

```
import AppComponent from '@/app/ index'
```

After run:

```
 npm run dev
```

Answer (score 2):

I do not know which version you are using, but the following attempts should work -all of them, under the assumption you export *Index.vue* with `name: AppComponent` :

```
import AppComponent from './app/index'
import AppComponent from '~/app/index'
import AppComponent from '@/app/index'
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem is very simple to solve and there are many solutions to it, i am going to present two:

1. install/ reinstall vue-template-compiler and vue-loader npm packages.
2. if the first solution does not work it means you have many broken or misconfigured npm packages, so run `npm install` so that it provides warning about all packages that should be installed but could not be, then install these packages and run `npm install` to see if everything is okay, if not install again the missing/broken packages, repeat the process until all the necessary packages are intalled.